# Error when converting text to CSV

Tags: csv, text, formatting

I'm a research assistant at Columbia University and I've been using Open Secret's bulk data on Campaign Lobbying. I've recently ran into an issue with the data in that the .txt files that they provide will not properly convert into .csv files because of formatting errors. I've solved most of the errors caused by extra commas and brackets, however, one error continues to be problematic. In one data-set (containing well over 3-million lines of data), is supposed to contain issue specific information in a single column in a single row. However, the text file is arranged in such a way that some of this text has been seperated by a line break and thus results in some information that is supposed to be present in a single column, has been split between different rows. Attached below is an example of this as presented in EmEditor. I'm wondering if there is a program or code that i can run this through in order to quickly fix these errors? It could be as simple as a line of code that looks at the first character of each line and if it isn't a numerical value, or is a letter or symbol, simply backspaces once in order to place the information on the previous line. I have very little coding experience and any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions.

In the find and replace window, check the 'Use Regular Expressions' box.

Use the below expressions in the find and the replace text box boxes.

Find: `\n([^\d])`

Replace: `\1`

This searches all occurences of newline character followed by a non-digit character and replaces it with only the non-digit character, thereby removing the newline character.

Comment: @Nagraj Thank you so much for the help. Your suggestion worked exactly as I wanted it to. Lines were successfully merged and extra lines removed.